# What is the meaning of "Find out to know is" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Find out to know is" in the following sentence,

> **Find out to know is** too much ginger harmful and what are the side effects of ginger in detail.

(Source: 11 Side Effects Of Ginger You Must Know
Reviewed by Merlin Annie Raj, Registered Dietitian October 22, 2019 by Ravi Teja Tadimalla )

Does it mean "What we need to know is too much ginger harmful" ?
Does "Find out to know is" mean "What we need to know is" ?

Comment: Perhaps it is an idiom in Indian English that I've never come across, but it doesn't make any sense in British English.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense in American English either. It is in any case ungrammatical and it's not obvious, at least to me, what the author's intent was or how it should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

> **Find out to know** is too much ginger harmful and what are the side
>   effects of ginger in detail.

The sentence is unclear because of several redundant words. It means:

> Find out (read about) the side effects and harms of excessive ginger intake in detail.